# Python - Pandas suggestion on how to format date column when values also include nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the date column values are not in datetime format and there are also nan values.

```
data_df = pd.read_csv(data.csv)
```

I ran the following: `df1[['INVOICE_DATE','DUE_DATE']] = pd.to_datetime(df1[['INVOICE_DATE','DUE_DATE']], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')`

```
+-----------------+------------------+
|   invoice_date  |      due_date    |
+------------------------------------+
|20200829065959.0 |20200829065959.0  |
+------------------------------------+
|      nan        |      nan         |
+------------------------------------+
|20200829065959.0 |20200829065959.0  |
+------------------------------------+
|      nan        |      nan         |
+------------------------------------+
|      nan        |      nan         |
+------------------------------------+
|20200829065959.0 |20200829065959.0  |
|------------------------------------+
```

I ran the following: `df1[['INVOICE_DATE','DUE_DATE']] = pd.to_datetime(df1[['INVOICE_DATE','DUE_DATE']], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')` and other solutions but no help

my expected output should be :

```
╔═════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║    Invoice_date     ║       Due_date       ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 2020/08/29 06:59:59 ║ 2020/08/29 06:59:59  ║
║ nan                 ║ 2020/08/29 06:59:59  ║
║ 2020/08/29 06:59:59 ║ nan                  ║
║ nan                 ║ 2020/08/29 06:59:59  ║
║ 2020/08/29 06:59:59 ║ nan                  ║
╚═════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Can anyone please suggestion. Thanks

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.Due_date, errors='coerce')`. You can check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: i tried pd.to_datetime(df.Due_date, errors='coerce') but the values were not updated in the right  order

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not one with pandas, but a problem with correctly parsing dates

```
import datetime
invoice_date = 20200829065959.0 # value from your csv
date_string = str(invoice_date).split('.')[0] # get rid of the decimal value, convert to string
record = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S') # create a date object
record_with_new_format = record.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') # create a formatted string from the date
# this gives us '2020/08/29 06:59:59'
```

From there you can work with the formatted date in pandas.

I am unaware of any advantages to parsing dates with pandas vs default python (I'm running python 3.8) but with this approach you can leverage pythons builtins